# Add upstreamProject or downstreamProject to an existing Jenkins job via REST

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm currently using a `freeStyleProject` for my job and I need to be able to add to the upstream projects from a remote script.

I have no problems with anything I can define in `config.xml` but upstream/downstream projects don't appear to be valid there.

I can see the upstream/downstream project here (sanitized)

```
http://SERVER/job/JOBNAME/api/xml
```

... but I can't figure out the correct way to update this value via REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no specialized mechanisms for setting upstream/downstream relations like there are for enabling/disabling a job, or setting its description.

You should be able to `GET http://SERVER/job/JOBNAME/config.xml` of the upstream project, modify the XML locally by inserting a `hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger` element in the `publishers` section (for a template, see a configured job's `config.xml`), and `POST` the modified file.

This is also explained in `/job/JOBNAME/api` section *Fetch/Update config.xml*.